# Зачем тут нужен подзапрос?

Tags: sql

```
SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE rating = (SELECT MAX(rating) FROM Customers);
```

Я думал, раз мы ищем из этой таблицы максимальное значение, то можно просто

```
rating = MAX(rating)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Мы ищем не просто "максимальное значение", а все записи с максимальным рейтингом. Для этого нам нужно получить значение этого самого максимального рейтинга. И выбрать все записи, у которых рейтинг совпадает с максимальным.

Что касается "просто `rating=MAX(rating)`" - а какую группировку используем для агрегации? Что нужно - записи с максимальным рейтингом среди всех клиентов или с максимальным рейтингом среди клиентов одного региона? И так далее, и тому подобное. Использование агригирующих функций в одном запросе с другими полями требует описания группировки. Поэтому такие вещи выносятся в подзапрос.